# Can't get Parsec to run on Ubuntu 22.04, missing libcrypto

Tags: apt, deb, libraries

i am currently trying to run Parsec on my Ubuntu 22.04 to connect to my remote Windows gaming rig.

On this support page: https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/115003477771-Using-Parsec-With-other-Linux-Distros

it says which libraries are required.

As far as i can tell via synaptic is that the only dependend package missing is "libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (or 1.1)"

If i search in synaptic for "libcrypto" i find a few libcrypto++ packages but none of them work.

Is there any other source where i can find a .deb file of this missing library?

Thank you guys in advance <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing libssl1.1, which provides libcrypto.so from 21.10 sources solved this for me. To do so, I followed the steps from this answer (MongoDB apparently has a similar issue): https://askubuntu.com/a/1403683

To quote the necessary commands from the answer:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

After the installation, I've removed the sources from 21.10 again. (Edit the created `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list` again and comment out the line by putting a `#` at the beginning.)

Comment: This is the correct answer as of July 2022, and it should also be in their documentation. Thanks!

Comment: This may have worked in July, but is now 404 `Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done                           
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Answer (score 2):

After Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) has reached End of Life this should work:

```
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
```