# Mongo db related key info being displayed everytime i run sudo apt get update

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, mongodb

I am using Ubuntu 22 LTS version and while trying to install mongo db I came to know that mongo db is yet to release a version for Ubuntu 22. So, i uninstalled mongo db midway and now even though my system doesnt have mongo-db i keep seeing the following message everytime I run sudo apt-get update :

> W:
> https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/Release.gpg:
> Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg),
> see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

Screenshot is also attached

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the mongodb entry from the apt source list. Run the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

Then run *apt update* . You will no longer see the warning.

Comment: Thanks that solved it.

Comment: Cheers. In case you still need to use mongodb on 22.04 without the official support, you can follow the guidelines from here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1416197/1607922